# Extruding a 2d vector is resulting in a object with gaps

Tags: mesh, extrude, svg

I'm attempting to take a 2d SVG image into Blender to turn it into a 3d object but the Extrude Faces operation is resulting in an object that doesn't look complete.

[image]

I'm wanting to use this 3d shape to countersink into one face of a larger object but thanks to the way it appears after the extrude step, it isn't usable.

I'm importing the image from SVG, converting to a mesh, entering edit mode, selecting it and using Extrude Faces.

The same steps performed on a font turned into an SVG have worked perfectly. Is there another operation or step that I am missing that will smooth out his image?

Thank you,
Steve

Comment: did you try the solidify modifier?

Comment: OK, that looks promising. I'll have a go at that and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: try right after converting to mesh, in edit mode, merge vertices > by distance and/or extrude vertices (enter edit mode, switch to Vertex select, press A to select all, then E to extrude ) If this won't fix missing faces problem, then the issue is in the SVG file itself and you should flatten it and/or fix gaps in the path using Inkscape or AI or similar software.